# reverse inetd / netcat-exec

Tags: linux, networking, unix

A neighbour is working on something with (in this case) embedded Linux systems that do large network transfers like:

```
dst$ nc -l 12345 | lz4 -d | consumerprogram
src$ producerprogram | lz4 -0 | nc fec0::2 12345
```

The `lz4` is a recent addition both for an extra checksum (the shell can do `set -o pipefail`) and to push more data over the network. However this means there are now three programs copying data around.

I had the brainwave of writing something that opens the socket, puts it on either stdin or stdout (not both like inetd does), and then `exec`s the `lz4` process. This should work, right?

```
dst$ ncexec -l 12345 -- lz4 -d | consumerprogram
src$ producerprogram | ncexec fec0::2 12345 -- lz4 -0
```

Before I write this… does something already exist to do that?

Comment: this probably would fit better on linux SE or SO

Comment: maybe, but they’d argue I want a software rec (if they even know of this SE site); crossposting isn’t welcome so let’s give it a shot, no?